# Prolog: two or more

Tags: list, prolog

Is there in prolog something like 'two or more' (or another option) to make the following shorter ?

```
rule(foo,  [bar,bar]). 
rule(foo,  [bar,bar,bar]).
rule(foo,  [bar,bar,bar,bar]).
rule(foo,  [bar,bar,bar,bar,bar]).
```

you can read it as: if there is a serie of n bars then assign the tag foo

Comment: This looks like "between 2 and 5 `bar`s". Do you really mean "one or more `bar`s"?

Comment: yes sorry i mean between 2 and 5

Comment: Well you should then edit the title of your question.

Comment: And altogether, attempt to write the question so that it is obvious what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`between/3` is probably what you're after:

```
rule(foo, L) :-
    between(2, 5, N),
    length(L, N),
    maplist(=(bar), L).
```

Comment: Yes! Thankyou, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: @Brutalized you are not supposed to change your question drastically. It invalidates the answers and comments given. Please change your question back and open a new question. But, if you give it some thought, you should be able to apply the technique I showed to solve that problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility

```
rule(foo, Out) :-
    random(2,6,N),
    length(Out,N),
    maplist(=(bar),Out).
```

Comment: To get the behavior as in the OP's example, you probably want `between/3` not `random/3`.

Comment: Perhaps.The OP said **"i mean between 2 and 5"**.